# TrueType fails to load in Android honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, truetype

I have searched a bit but all the answers on the exception is related to people loading the wrong font.

However, I am trying to load a TrueType font. It works for the majority of the devices I have tested on. However, when trying to load on the Tab 10.1 running Android 3.1 or EEEPad running 3.2 I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
```

The complete stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{se.healthyheroes.android.app/se.healthyheroes.android.app.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
    at se.healthyheroes.android.app.LoginActivity.initViews(LoginActivity.java:154)
    at se.healthyheroes.android.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:94)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    ... 11 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
    at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:147)
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:121)
    at se.healthyheroes.android.app.LoginActivity.initViews(LoginActivity.java:154)
    at se.healthyheroes.android.app.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:94)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

You might wonder about line 154 in LoginActivity. 
The line is this one:

```
Typeface tf =(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/style_5784.ttf"));
```

The font is located under "assets/fonts/style_5784.ttf" in my project in Eclipse. 
The really weird thing is that it works on all the other devices except honeycomb.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause the exception? Could the font be broken or perhaps there is something as simple as the name of the file? The only thing I managed to understand by searching around for it is that it could be the font that is broken somehow.

Comment: This a punt on my part, hence this is a comment. Have you tried converting your font to the OTF format and then loading it? I've only ever loaded OTF fonts in Android. You can use Fontforge, as described in its FAQ: http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: @AsimIhsan I will give it a try at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon looking further into this error it doesn't look like the error is being causing by the font name. The error is occurring inside of native code which is most likely changed in Honeycomb and cannot be debugged through a stack trace.

Until the source has been released we will not be able to look further into the error.

Comment: Yeah. Ended up just skipping that font.